# Is it possible to connect a H2 database through the dblink of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I checked the [documents](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/dblink.html) from PostgreSQL's website, it doesn't mention whether I can use it to connect other types of databases, like H2, SQL Server, etc.

Comment: look for foreign data wrappers https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

Comment: No. Postgres' dblink can only connect to other Postgres databases. And the manual clearly states that: "*dblink is a module that supports connections to other PostgreSQL databases from within a database session*"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately **dblink** can only be used to connect other **Postgres** databases as @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned in the comment above, and we can also find the statement from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/dblink.html)

Comment: You could however create a linked table in H2 pointing to the Postgres database.

Comment: yeah, I've tried it, thanks, buddy @a_horse_with_no_name